# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist with a login window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

I made a code with several modules... a 'main2.py', an 'Appimage.py', a 'spe_widget.py', when I run the program from main2.py, everything works fine. I then wanted to add a connection window which after a test launches the program as before, and there, it no longer works, I get the message

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

I searched but I don't find anything... maybe you have an idea... I kept the codes as minimal as possible so that the error was still there, ...

Main2.py:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from spe_widget import *
class Window(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('AMC44 Connect')
        self.tabs=ctk.CTkTabview(self,fg_color='#2C3E50',segmented_button_selected_color='#2C3E50')
        self.tabs.add('PROJETS')
        self.tabs.pack(padx=5,pady=5,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
        self.page_projet=ProjetFrame(self.tabs.tab('PROJETS'),self)
        self.page_projet.pack(padx=5,pady=5,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

Appimage.py:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageGrab
import os

rep_plan='ressources'

def charge_photo(nom_projet,code_projet,resize,dim=280):
    print(f'le nom du projet selectionné est {nom_projet} et le code est {code_projet}')
    image_path=''
    if nom_projet=='Main_Img':
        image_path='ressources\\Main_img.jpg' 
    elif nom_projet=='00':
        image_path='ressources\\00.jpg'       
    else:
        image_path_by_name=rep_plan + '\\'+ str(nom_projet) + '\\'+ str(nom_projet) + '.jpeg'
        image_path_by_code=rep_plan + '\\'+ str(code_projet) + '\\'+ str(code_projet) + '.jpeg'
        
        if os.path.exists(image_path_by_code):
            image_path=image_path_by_code
            
        elif os.path.exists(image_path_by_name):
            image_path=image_path_by_name
            
        else:
            image_path='ressources\\00.jpg'

    print(f'le chemin de l image est {image_path}')
    if image_path:
        try:
            image=Image.open(image_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'une erreur d ouverture de l image {e}')
            image=None
    #redimensionner l'image
    if resize:
        lo,ho=image.size
        if lo>ho:
            h=dim*ho/lo
            l=dim
        else:
            l=dim*lo/ho
            h=dim
        image=image.resize((int(l),int(h)),Image.LANCZOS) if image else None
    photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) if image else None
   
    return photo
```

spe_widget.py:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

from Appimage import *

from PIL import Image


class ProjetFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    
    def __init__(self,master,winstance,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master=master
        self.winstance=winstance
        self.loaded_photo=None


        


        self.image_frame=ctk.CTkFrame(self,border_color='black',border_width=2)
        self.image_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='nsew')

        self.of_img_init=charge_photo('00',None,resize=True)
        self.of_img_label=tk.Label(self.image_frame,image=self.of_img_init)
        self.of_img_label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

login.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import customtkinter as ctk


class LoginWindow(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('AMC44 Connect')
        self.geometry('+560+400')
        #création du dictionnaire des entré du formulaire
        self.loglabel=ctk.CTkLabel(self,text='login: ')
        self.loglabel.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.logentry=ctk.CTkEntry(self)
        
        self.logentry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        self.mdplabel=ctk.CTkLabel(self,text='Mot de passe: ')
        self.mdplabel.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
        self.mdpentry=ctk.CTkEntry(self,show='*')
        
        self.mdpentry.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label_info=ctk.CTkLabel(self,text='')
        self.label_info.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=5, pady=5)
        self.btn=ctk.CTkButton(self,text='connexion',command=self.connexion)
        self.btn.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=5, pady=5)

    def connexion(self):
     
        test=True
        if test:
            self.label_info.configure(text='connexion réussie')
            self.quit()
            import Main2
            window=Main2.Window()
            window.mainloop()
            
        else:
            self.label_info.configure(text='impossible de se connecter')

logwindow = LoginWindow()
logwindow.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help, i don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: Such error is most probably caused by multiple instances of `Tk()` (`CTk` inherits from `Tk`).

Comment: ok, but how can I do???@acw1668, ok, do you think it's because of the inheritance of loginWindow(ctk.CTk) and Window(ctk.CTk)?

Comment: @acw1668, ok, do you think it's because of the inheritance of loginWindow(ctk.CTk) and Window(ctk.CTk)?

Comment: Most probably.  Use `CTkToplevel` instead for `LoginWindow`.

Comment: thank you @acw1668! that's what I thought.... I've been looking for quite some time for the structure to put in place for a login window without success, the structure that I have allows me to only load what is necessary for the login window, then once the login and password are recognized, then we load all the necessary libraries and modules, including many database tables...